# Read some products Data from a csv file using python in command line

Tags: python, django, web

i have a csv file which have information about all the products so i want to perform some basic functions like

- You have to show data based on user selection.
- User will select filters he wants to apply (he can select multiple fields).
- Also user can select the fields he wants to see like he can select full item or he wants to see
  only price of item or he wants to see some specific fields

  **as am new to it so kindly help to learn. I have read python basics like its Datastructure , loops, file system**

Here is the sample Data
[image]

Comment: If you want all this functionality in a web application you are asking for a lot. A start is to read about how you can create dataframes from CSV files with Pandas.

Comment: not all just one or two may be show specific column as user enter in commandLine

Comment: All of this is easy to do using Pandas. Read about it and experiment with the CSV files in the console. After that it will be clear what you need to do, if you know the basics of the django web-framework.